# I'm trying to access data received in the body as json, but getting undefined

Tags: node.js

```
commandline:
curl -d '{number:"1009732533765201",once:1009732533765201}' -X POST  http://localhost:3000

code:
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.dir(request.param)

  if (request.method == 'POST') {
    console.log('POST')
    var body = ''
    request.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data
      l = data.body
      console.log('Partial body: ' + body, l)
    })
    request.on('end', function() {
      l = body
      console.log('Body: ' + body, l, l.number)
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
      response.end('post received')
    })
  } else {
    console.log('GET')
    var html = `
            <html>
                <body>
                    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">Name: 
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>`
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    response.end(html)
  }
})

console log shows l.number as undefined:
POST
Partial body: {number:"1009732533765201"} undefined
Body: {number:"1009732533765201"} {number:"1009732533765201"} undefined
```

l = body is logging as undefined. I want to assign the body to a variable so i can work with it as a json object , so i can do something like l.number, and have the number so i can work with the post data. Is there something i'm missing here? I'm moving from python to json so i'm new to this and looking for help so i can access body data as a json object so i can work with it. Thanks

ANSWERED: I had to use JSON.parse. this works. New code that works is:

```
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.dir(request.param)

  if (request.method == 'POST') {
    console.log('POST')
    var body = ''
    request.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data
      l = JSON.parse(body)
      console.log('Partial body: ' + body, l)
    })
    request.on('end', function() {
      l = JSON.parse(body)
      console.log('Body: ' + body, l, l.number)
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
      response.end('post received')
    })
  } else {
    console.log('GET')
    var html = `
            <html>
                <body>
                    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">Name:
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>`
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    response.end(html)
  }
})

console.log:
Partial body: {"number":"1009732533765201"} { number: '1009732533765201' }
Body: {"number":"1009732533765201"} { number: '1009732533765201' } 1009732533765201
```

Comment: I guess, in the request, you should access the body like `data.body`, have you tried printing the whole `data`?

Comment: In node cli, i can do this: > l= {number:"1009732533765201",once:1009732533765201}
{ number: '1009732533765201', once: 1009732533765201 }
> l.number
'1009732533765201'   But from the program above, it's not assigning to "l" like it's a JSON object, which is confusing me as i need to work with the data as a JSON object so i can return the right data for each different number posted. Does that make sense? An assignment like that works from console, but not in the program

Comment: @oppressionslayer where is the variable 'l' defined?

Comment: @oppressionslayer use `body-parser` https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: l = data.body in the POST method, and i also tried l = body. It's in the request.on sections.  you can see from the console output it can assign it to L, but i can't access it like a JSON. like i can't do l.number, console.log shows that as undefined

Comment: In req.end you are not parsing the body.